# Android signature protection and exported="false"

Tags: android, ipc, android-contentprovider

I want my ContentProvider to be available in my application only, 
for this purpose I set the `exported` attribute of ContentProvider to be `false`

```
android:exported="false"
```

This works fine and Android throws `SecurityException` whenever some other app tries to access the ContentProvider

**Question:
Does it make sense to add "signature protection permission" as an additional protection?**

The application consists of multiple processes and ContentProvider is used for inter-process communication and **there is no need to communicate with other apps**

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible, and useful if the minimum level of your application [is lower then 17](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/provider-element.html#exported) :

> Because this attribute was introduced in API level 17, all devices
>   running API level 16 and lower behave as though this attribute is set
>   "true".

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is most secure way to protect the content provider with a permission you define. Make it a signature a permission so only apps signed with your certificate are allowed to get it.

You can also refer [developer console](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element.html#plevel)

Comment: thanks for the answer. I'm curious if it's needed at all because there is no intention in communicating with other apps ?